# Time limit exceeded Error - When I try to run Python 3 code

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

- Starting to learn Python 3 on HackerRank when I run this code I get
  this error:

***Time limit exceeded
Your code did not execute within the time limits. Please optimize your code. For more information on execution time limits, refer to the environment page***

Here is a link to the question on Hackerrank.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/repeated-string/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=warmup

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

#
# Complete the 'repeatedString' function below.
#
# The function is expected to return a LONG_INTEGER.
# The function accepts following parameters:
#  1. STRING s
#  2. LONG_INTEGER n
#

def repeatedString(s, n):
    Write your code here
    i = 0
    aCount = 0
    
    while i <= n:
        if 'a' == s[i]:
            aCount += 1
            ++i
        else:
            ++i
            
            print(aCount)
            return aCount 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    s = input()

    n = int(input().strip())

    result = repeatedString(s, n)

    fptr.write(str(result) + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Comment: I'm afraid, `++i` doesn't do what you expect it to do. Use `i+=1`.

Comment: As a tip you don't really need to index into the string - you can just read directly from the substring of `s`: `s[:n]`. Otherwise, if you must index into it, you should consider counting in a `for` loop with `range`.

Answer (score 0):

Even though `++i` is syntactically valid, it doesn't do what one would expect it to do, coming from a C-like language. In Python, `++i` is just unary `+` applied to `i` twice (`+(+i)`), without changing it. The Python way of incrementing a variable is `i+=1`.

Answer (score 0):

You're running the while loop from 0 to n, maximum value for n is 10^12. That while loop is running 10^12 times in worst case. That's why time exceeded. Try to optimize code.

Try this code

```
def repeatedString(s, n):
    #Write your code here
    aCount = 0
    
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if 'a' == s[i]:
            aCount += 1
    aCount*=(n//len(s))
    x=n%len(s)
    for i in range(x):
        if 'a' == s[i]:
            aCount += 1
            
    return aCount
```

Comment: *"Try this code"* is really not a good answer. A good answer explains what the problem is, what needs to be changed, and why that solves the problem.

Comment: Also why is it a good idea to _give_ an answer for this problem to someone who is supposed to be trying to learn? They don’t learn anything (unless your answer also doesn’t let them ‘pass’ this question) especially because you didn’t bother to include any explanation; even then, surely the best way to learn is for the learner to try and succeed through their own efforts perhaps hrough guidance rather than solution-gifting.

Comment: Thank you, i am new here, i will teach from next answers